# Pervasive 10.30 query between servers (link servers)

Tags: pervasive

We are using 3 Pervasive v10.3 servers in our company. There are in 3 different locations and all is connected via VPN. 
Is there any possibility to set in one server link to another? I want to query on one server databases located on another servers.

PS. Sorry for my English ....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link servers within Pervasive PSQL.  Your client application can access multiple servers but you cannot write one query to access multiple servers at the same time.

Comment: So I have to use some ETL tools (like Pentaho PDI) to integrate data between my servers

Comment: You would have to query each server separately and combine the data to the format you want after the fact.  If your ETL tool can do that, you're ready to go.